# How to charge sales tax only if a customer is out of country and chooses specific shipping method?

Tags: shipping, tax

Can someone tell me how and if it's possible in the magento 1.9.2 (x) admin, where I can setup a way to charge my NY sales tax on an order IF a customer is in Canada AND they choose a specific shipping method (in this case, I'm offering local pickup - but if they do this, I have to charge sales tax if they are picking up the item where I'm located).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot apply a tax rule to a specific shipping method out of the box with Magento. To accomplish this, you could create a custom extension to override the `collect` method inside `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax` and get the shipping method using `$address->getShippingMethod()`. You could also determine if the customer is based in Canada by looking at their shipping address via `$address->getCountry()`.

If the shipping method is local pickup and the customer is based in Canada, you can return `parent::collect($address)`:

```
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    if ($address->getShippingMethod() == 'flatrate_flatrate' && $address->getCountry() == 'CA') {
        return parent::collect($address);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

[Learn how to override core models in Magento](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-overriding-in-magento-models--cms-23354) and [check out an example of overriding `Mage_Tax_Model_Sales_Total_Quote_Tax`](https://github.com/taxjar/taxjar-magento-extension/blob/master/app/code/community/Taxjar/SalesTax/Model/Sales/Total/Quote/Tax.php).

From there, you'd just need to collect sales tax based on your NY shipping origin. Under System > Configuration > Tax you'd set **Tax Calculation Based On** to **Shipping Origin**. Set up a new tax rule with your NY tax rate.